# Having a recent-C++ compiled .so run on older systems if no std symbols are exposed

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, abi

My goal is to use recent C++ features like smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr` at least) for a linux C++ so library which should run on multiple distributions (obviously recompiling it for each platform). The oldest gcc I'm targeting is [4.4.x since I need to support RHEL6](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19458). It seems smart pointers are supported for a simple program like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> aa;
    return 0;
}
```

My library will expose a C API (`extern`), I don't use exceptions nor C++ types in the API. I'm [linking statically both libstdc++ and libgcc and marking all symbols local except the API exported ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51026785/3834459).

I have another question now: in the situation above will a library compiled with a newer gcc (e.g. 5.0 or even 6.0) work on an older system like RHEL6 with a default installed gcc 4.4.x **reliably**?

In theory using more recent C++ features but not exposing any of that in symbols or API should work but I'm not terribly sure and I'd rather ask.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes.

Actually, [Red Hat posted a blog item](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/02/05/gcc5-and-the-c11-abi/) about your situation:

> Users that depend on third-party libraries or plugin interfaces that still use the old ABI can build their code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and everything should work fine. In most cases, it will be obvious when this flag is needed because of **errors from the linker** complaining about unresolved symbols involving `__cxx11`.
>
> [The] plan for [the C++11] ABI change has been to leave the soname (and the existing binary interface) alone, and express the new ABI using different mangled names.

Since you compile with libstdc++ statically, all applications will work reliably, or fail to link. When this happens, change your compilation flags to add `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

---

As a summary, you shouldn't care about API changes, only about ABI changes. And this time, the GNU team got it right!

Comment: There is nothing to do with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro.

Comment: This macro is only about building old stuff with a new `libstdc++` and he does not want to bring new `libstdc++` to the executing machines, as I understood.

Comment: I just want my .so to execute reliably on both newer and older machines (starting from the aforementioned RHEL6 as the oldest architecture I need to support, the rest ranges from Ubuntu16-18 to CentOS7). If I can do that while using newer C++ features, all the better.

Comment: @Dean If you link statically, then it does not matter, you have all stuff inside already, if you do not then you have build libstdc++ you are building with for every platform you plan to run it on. Btw, you need to have a build machine of the same distribution for each type of it you have in production.

Comment: @Yuki I was more referring to symbols clashes if the user application which loads my `.so` library uses another version of the standard library as well. Not sure what would happen then and that's why I'm taking all the 'mark symbols as local except the API ones' precautions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you compile and run your library on the same distribution, i.e. `libc`, `libpthread`, etc. Then it should totally work, the only thing to care is `libgcc` (gcc runtime library). It might behave different if the versions are different, like 1.1 and 1.2. So make sure you are on the same versions, i.e. gcc-5/6 did not bring any new versions of `libgcc`, what is I am not aware about, and I tend to think that it is version 1 everywhere, so no worries here.